# NAT interface stops working as soon as host only adapter interface is up

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, nat

I have two virtual interfaces, one configured as NAT and another as host only adapter. The NAT interface is intended to provide Internet access from inside the virtual box (to pull Docker images, etc) while the host only adapter is for communication between host and quest.

My /etc/network/interfaces is

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 193.168.56.101
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast 193.168.56.255
    gateway 193.168.56.1

auto enp0s3 
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
```

I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 5.2.18_Ubuntu. The guest is Ubuntu Server 5.0.0-13-generic, the host is Ubuntu Mate 4.18.0-18-generic.

The NAT interface (enp0s3) works correctly as long as the host only interface (enp0s8) is down. As soon as I put the second interface up (with `ifup`), the Internet stops being accessible. It is nicely accessible again as soon as I put the second interface down but I need both working at the same time.

With both interfaces up, ifconfig on the virtual machine gives

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255    

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 193.168.56.101  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 193.168.56.255
```

How can the machine confuse 10.0.2.15 with 193.168.53.101?

Ifconfig on host gives

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.43  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 193.168.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 193.168.56.255
```

Most I was able to do is to add the routing rule to enp0s3 so that the guest can be accessed from host at localhost rerouted port. I however would still like to understand what is going wrong and how to get both interfaces working.

Comment: Did you install virutalbox guest tools?

Comment: I have just done as explained in https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm. I have rebooted the virtual machine after that. This did not make any difference.

Comment: Remove or comment out the `gateway` and `broadcast` fields.

Comment: Yes, this worked. This is the answer.

Comment: I've not solid reason for this. I've also tested this in my setup. Same issue occurs.